# How to imitate Opera 10.50's custom UI?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, opera

For the past two days i have been looking around the net to find how Opera made their pre-alpha build 
with that UI. I mean its like built with windows shell 
here are some screenshots

[image] [image]

any tutorials , books or videos would be helpful

P.S. I also saw the win 7 SDK but its all C++ samples and i learn C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for c# there is
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3574

especcially look at GlassForm class it certainly allows that icons on the transparent filed in the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be helpful too:

[Aero Glass inside a WPF Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/adam_nathan/archive/2006/05/04/589686.aspx)

Comment: Is opera going WPF, or did you just pick that as a good intro to using Aero in general?

Comment: No , i don't think opera is going WPF, and yes i just want an intro to Aero in general , and how did they added the buttons to the title bar ? if its possible to give C# examples

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this tutorial out?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FancyNetForms.aspx

It looks quite good...

Comment: OK, well the guy on CodeProject - Sacha Baber is a good one to look at WPF stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom build something like that using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), a sample of what you can build is http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar-wpf/